# Plesk : Date of domains is not the date of the server

Tags: plesk, plesk-onyx

I have a problem with the date management in Plesk. The server has a right date (# date), and the Plesk console too (Tools and Settings > System Date and Time). But all the websites on the server have a -2 hours date and I can't figure out how to solve this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it.
In plesk the date.timezone in the php.ini was empty. I went to Tools & Settings > PHP Settigns > 7.1.32 FPM application > php.ini and add my timezone.
Job's done.